# How to go over all inputs that have a custom attribute

Tags: javascript

I have a form with checkboxes.
All of the checkboxes have an attribute called att, which contains several numbers that are separated by commas.

I'd like to create a function that gets a number, goes over all the checkboxes and checks all the checkboxes that their att attribute contains that number.

Can please someone point me at the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do something like

```
function myfunc(num)
{
    $(":checkbox[att!='']").each(function()
    {
        var i, l, values = $(this).attr("att").split(",");
        for (i = 0, l = values.length; i < l; ++i)
        {
            if (values[i] == num)
            {
                $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery you would use the [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to get all elements where an attribute contains a certain value.

```
$('input[att*="100"]').val('input has 100 in it!');
```

Comment: The thing is that att="1000,12,14" contains 100 in it, but it actually doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This loops over all `input` elements and gives you an array containing the values of `att` (split using the comma), so I'd add some logic to pick out only checkboxes:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input'); i++)
{
  var att_array = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].getAttribute('att').split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all inputs with the attribute ATTR and then alerts the val of each of those. You can, of course, do whatever you want with the val when you have it.

```
$("input[ATTR]").each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("ATTR"))
})
```

If you want to limit this to checkboxes, change the selector as is shown below

```
$(":checkbox[ATTR]").each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("ATTR"))
})
```

Comment: Good call. I tend to do it out of habit I think.